# Istio Ingress with AWS NLB IP mode

Tags: kubernetes, nlb, istio-gateway, aws-nlb

I've been trying to deploy istio ingress with nlb for my cluster. Currently I'm using the `service annotation` to attach the nlb with my istio ingress.
I have a test server behind the cluster to test my curl command against the nlb, and all the routing has been set up. For all the curl I'm testing with http on port 80.

So the issue I'm running into is that, if I set my load balancer type as `nlb` with

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb",
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-security-groups: "<some security group",
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true",
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "false",
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-manage-backend-security-group-rules: "false",
```

it works, and the curl test will pass, but if I want to turn on the ip mode with

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb-ip",
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-security-groups: "<some security group",
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true",
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "false",
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-manage-backend-security-group-rules: "false",
```

the curl will just get timed out when trying to establish tcp connection.

I'm wondering, is there anything specific I need to set when turning on the nlb-ip mode for the nlb?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you have any target group has set in your new NLB

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the EC2 security group is blocking my IP address...

The previously working version was either not setting the security group correctly, or not using my client IP adress as the source IP.

Comment: Hello. You should not add additional information in Answer section. Just update your original post.

Comment: @ViktorKhilin Hi Viktor, thanks for the reminder. This is not additional information. My friend helped resolve this issue so I was just posting the answer to my own question.